# How to reset password to different domain in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When reseting it's password I need the user to specify which domain the user wants to change its passwords (I have two domains, web domain and an internal domain). I'm not sure how to start this, I already have the code that resets the password I just need to specify the domain. How should I approche this? I haven't found anything specific in the Microsoft documentation. Does anyone have a reliable source that I can understand how this works?

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
       
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
           
            return NotFound($"The user dos not exist'{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }
        var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, code, Input.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                return Page();
            }

        }
        return RedirectToPage("./ResetPasswordConfirmation");

    }
```

Comment: Does those sites share same identity database?

Comment: I think so, not completely sure